# Paypal button callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal

I'm trying to start charging for my website using paypal. I know the very basics of making a paypal button, but I would like my button to allow you to pay and then take you back to a page on my website that generates a password. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Variable is called [return](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/). You can set it up in your HTML where the PP button is located. For the future, you should be more specific and always include code snippets.